# Is there a mac osx web browser that provides access to the Mac's hardware accelerometer?

Tags: javascript, macos, accelerometer

At some point in the past, I believe that in certain Mac web browsers, it was possible to get genuine `DeviceMotionEvent` events using the Mac's hardware accelerometer, as per this spec:

```
http://www.w3.org/TR/orientation-event/
```

Now, at least in Google Chrome 46, `devicemotion` events seem to fire exactly once, with an acceleration that has `null` fields for x/y/z.  (This technically meets the spec, since firing with null fields means that the accelerometer isn't available.)

Does anyone know if there is a Mac browser that returns accelerometer values to Javascript?  If so, which browser, which events, and is there anything special that a user must do when running the browser to enable accelerometer access?

Comment: I certainly had it working in Chrome. Maybe they broke it in newest version; could you try Safari, anyway?

Comment: Safari 9.0 also meets the spec, but by returning a single DeviceMotionEvent with null values for acceleration.{x,y,z}

Comment: Doesn't work on Firefox 39.0 or 40.0.3, either.  Is there maybe a command-line flag for one of the browsers that would enable it?